# Select and count record from database using codeigniter active query method

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

I have two tables in my database "tbl_room_info" & "tbl_room_image".

### **tbl_room_info structure:**

### room_id | room_name | room_details

### **tbl_room_image structure:**

### room_id | room_image_path

now i want get all room information from my tbl_room_info table and also count my room image number from tbl_room_image table. for example consider tbl_room_info has 1 record having room_id '2' and tbl_room_image also have same room_id who has 5 room images. i want to achieve all information in my view page like this:

**Room Name | Room Details | Room Image Number**

```
 1          room details     5

 2          room details     6
```

my problem is that i can get this by normal mysql query like:

```
     SELECT `tbl_room_info`.*, COUNT('tbl_room_image.*') AS imc FROM (`tbl_room_info`, `tbl_room_image`) WHERE `tbl_room_info`.`room_id` = tbl_room_image.room_id GROUP BY `tbl_room_info`.`room_id`
```

but i want this codeigniter active record format. here is my query it's not worked properly. plz help

```
    $this->db->select('tbl_room_info.*', 'count(tbl_room_image.*) as imc');
    $this->db->from('tbl_room_info, tbl_room_image');
    $this->db->where('tbl_room_info.room_id = tbl_room_image.room_id');
    $this->db->group_by('tbl_room_info.room_id');
    return $this->db->get()->result();
```

here is my view:

```
    <tbody>
    <?php foreach($roomlists as $roomlist){?>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $roomlist->room_type;?></td>
            <td><?php echo $roomlist->room_name;?></td>
            <td><?php echo $roomlist->room_details;?></td>
            <td>Total Pictures <span class="badge"><?php echo $roomlist->imc;?></span></td>
        </tr>
    <?php }?>
    </tbody>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Active Record's JOIN - **`$this->db->join();`**. Try below -

```
$this->db->select('tbl_room_info.*, count(tbl_room_image.room_image_path) as imc', FALSE);
$this->db->from('tbl_room_info');
$this->db->join('tbl_room_image', 'tbl_room_info.room_id = tbl_room_image.room_id');
$this->db->group_by('tbl_room_info.room_id');
$query = $this->db->get();

echo $this->db->last_query(); exit;  // print resulting query
print_r($query->result()); exit;     // check resulting array

if($query->num_rows() > 0)
    return $query->result();
return false;
```

**Edit (explanation of the answer):**

The second parameter (optional) in **`$this->db->select();`** is actually a `boolean` value (should be either TRUE/FALSE). By default the value is **`TRUE`**. **`TRUE`** means protect whatever inside the select with **`backticks`**. **`FALSE`** means the opposite i.e prevent protecting it from **`backticks`**. Why we did this, since we were adding **`COUNT`** in the select as well, it is getting protected by **`backticks`** i.e **`COUNT(tbl_room_image.room_image_path) as imc`** which is definitely **`no such column found`** error.

Comment: it's not working. I cannot get the number of image count value in my view page that is "count(tbl_room_image.*) as imc" value from this query part.

Comment: I got the error. Replace this `count(tbl_room_image.*) as imc` with this `count(tbl_room_image.room_image_path) as imc`. I'm sure it'll work. Check edits.

Comment: i get this error in my view:
A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined property: stdClass::$imc

Comment: Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [room_id] => 1 [room_type] => 1 [room_name] => Queen Room [room_details] => Queen Size bed Sleeps up to 2 )  [1] => stdClass Object ( [room_id] => 2 [room_type] => 1 [room_name] => Two Double room [room_details] => Two double beds Sleeps up to 2 ))

still not getting Number of image form a particular room_id

Comment: Its strange you are not getting `imc`. Can you print the query? Check edits.

Comment: Here is the query result, and it shows it cannot count image from tbl_room_image.
SELECT `tbl_room_info`.* FROM (`tbl_room_info`) JOIN `tbl_room_image` ON `tbl_room_info`.`room_id` = `tbl_room_image`.`room_id` GROUP BY `tbl_room_info`.`room_id`

Comment: Add an extra parameter `FALSE` in `select`. Try that if it works.

Comment: O, man you are truly genius. It worked!! Thank you so much. one last question what was the problem? and how this extra parameter helps to solve the problem. Thanks again.

Comment: Happy to help :). Kindly check the edits for the explanation.